# unable to ping Linux server from my windows machine

Tags: ping

I have installed linux 6.0 on vmware , its static ip is 192.168.208.10 but I am unable to **ping** it with windows machine

its giving error connection time out

Comment: what is your networking configuration?

Comment: windows 192.168.208.0  , 255.255.255.0

Comment: Linux 192.168.208.10  subnet - 255.255.255.0

Comment: is the vm network bridged?

Comment: no its host only